# Generate and display series of fractions

Tags: arrays, matlab, fractions

I want to generate a series like:

```
1/2, -1/3, 1/4, -1/5, ..., 1/100
```

My code is not displaying in fraction.

```
i= 2 : 100,  k=((-1).^(i+1)).*i, y= (1/k)
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are performing arithmetic operations on integers.  Matlab returns results of the same type as the operands, hence no fractions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution:

```
k = 100;

num = repmat([1 -1],1,(k / 2)).';
num_str = num2str(num);

den = (1:k).';
den_str = num2str(den,'%-d');

disp([num_str repmat('\',k,1) den_str]);
```

Output:

```
 1\1  
-1\2  
 1\3  
-1\4  
 1\5  
-1\6  
 1\7  
-1\8  
 1\9  
-1\10 
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly, I appreciate.

Comment: You're welcome. If this is the solution you were looking for, please mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You should put semicolon between your commands and also choosing `./` instead of `/` for division. In addition, there is a fallacy in your expression. the power of `-1` should be `i`.

```
i= 2 : 100;  
k=((-1).^(i)).*i;
y= 1./k;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you work with [**`double`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html), you will get your result as floating point numbers. If you want fractions, you need to do the calculations symbolically:

```
syms ii k y

for ii =  1 : 10
    k(ii) = ((-1).^(ii+1)).*ii;
    y(ii) = (1/k(ii));
end

y =

[ 1, -1/2, 1/3, -1/4, 1/5, -1/6, 1/7, -1/8, 1/9, -1/10]
```